# Today Extension invalidated after I scroll the extension out of view

Tags: ios, widget, today-extension

On iOS9 , after I scroll the extension out of view, I get a console log error:

Sep  2 14:36:34 {myPhoneName} SpringBoard[2570] : plugin {myExtensionBundleName} invalidated

then after scrolling it back into view, it is unresponsive (i.e. none of the widget buttons are responsive).  Until I close the Today screen and re-open it the widget remains unresponsive.

Thanks in advance for any guidance to help diagnose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably because your debugger is connected to your Today extension.  What about doing this...
Stop running your app/extension in Xcode.
Uninstall your Today extension (removing from Notification Centre).
Install it again.

Check if your buttons are responsible after scrolling it out.

Comment: Incredibly, this solves the problem. After running a Today Extension via Xcode, you have to remove and re-install it in Notification Center for it to behave correctly.

Comment: I've spent several days thinking my problem was excessive memory consumption causing my extension to be killed. But no, this was the solution. Many, many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But any idea as to why this happens? If I reconnect the debugger latter on it seems to work just fine (both the debugger and the widget).